# Check if lines are collinear with Geometry Nodes

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, vertices, lines

I want to check if two connected lines are collinear. If yes then I want to place at the middle point an object. To give the collinearity a little bit of tolerance $±5°$ would be a nice addition.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this, for example, by comparing the direction vectors between the points, thus creating a selection.

Something like this:

[image]

Here I get the direction vectors of the edges with the node `Edge Vertices`, and compare them with the node `Compare`.

The epsilon of $0.087$ corresponds to an angle of $5°$ (The values are in radians!).

Additionally I use the node `Compare` to select a certain point.

Both selections together then result in the selection for the instantiation of the desired object at the desired point, as soon as the angle between the two lines is less than $5°$.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: Wow works like a charme!!

Comment: I never knew _Equal_ did that ! .. that's half-a-xillion Dot-Products I'll never get back... :)

Comment: @RobinBetts :D ...This comment made my day. For others: it's a `Compare` node set to *Vector*

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, since the correct answer is already taken:

[image]

Comment: classic style +1

Comment: Wow, i dont really know what it will do but i have an assumption. You can create many vertices on one line and the angle defines the visibility? That would be my 2nd question, because i tried and failed. But i am failing also on this here. Please take a look on this pic. Must be exact the same like yours... https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsBbq.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5rl4.png BTW: something happend to my account, have a new one, i

Comment: @Probber perhaps the extrusion has an inconsistent direction, I don't think it's reasonable to work on this answer, as I said it's just for fun :D